# YouTube Player API video playback pauses in Multi Window on Android N

Tags: youtube-api, android-youtube-api, android-7.0-nougat, multi-window

When I play a video using YouTube Player API and open another application in multi-window mode my activity receives onPause and video playback pauses. I expected YouTube Player API to follow the guidelines at http://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html#lifecycle

"we recommend that activities that play video not pause the video in their onPause() handlers. Instead, they should pause video in onStop(), and resume playback in onStart()."

YouTube app works as expected.

Comment: Did you got a answer?